# AWS CA ssl certificates not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, routes, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I created a CSR on the AWS Linux server and used this to create a self signed CA certificate which I then installed but get common name and host name mismatch errors.

Can somebody tell me what I have to do to correct the problem as the common name IP is internal to Amazon and the host IP is public so how do I create a workable certificate?

I am not a programmer but this is the last step of my site development. SSL is fine But I need to get the certificate working. Thanks

Comment: Did you use the hostname you're using to access the site as the common name when generating the self-signed cert?

Answer (score 0):

I did use my domain.net as the common name but I think he answer lies in my changing the hostname on the AWS /etc/sysconfig/network file.  This was set as HOSTNAME=localhost.local when I created the original CSR.pem file and certificate.

I changed localhost.local to mydomain.net, created another csr.pem file and certificate and SSL is working. I should add I previously created an elastic IP and attached this to the server and in Route 53 allocated the domain name to the instance. There was no information to change the instance HOSTNAME in the network file.

When you find the answer its obvious, finding the answer was the problem.

Many thanks